# Code in a method from protocole is not executed

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new in ios development and I am creating an app with 2 view controller.I use use Protocols and Delegates to send data from one controller to the preview controller.The data pass fine.My problem is that the code which is in the method from protocol that is implemented in the controller who gets the data is not execute.An NSLOG that is in the method is execute but the rest of gode no.
Any ideas why this happening?

Code from Controller who sends the data:

.h

```
@class GeoCoding_controller;

@protocol GeoContDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)addItemViewController:(GeoCoding_controller *)controller didFinishEnteringItem:     (NSString *)item;
 @end
```

.m

```
   NSString *itemToPassBack = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@,%@",final_loc[indexPath.row][@"form_address"],final_loc[indexPath.row][@"lat"],final_loc[indexPath.row][@"lng"]];;

   First_view_controller *first_cont = [self .storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"first_view"];

[self presentViewController:first_cont animated:YES completion:nil];

[self.delegate addItemViewController:self didFinishEnteringItem:itemToPassBack];
```

Code in Controller who gets the data:

.h

```
@interface First_view_controller : UIViewController<CLLocationManagerDelegate,GMSMapViewDelegate,GeoContDelegate>
```

.m

```
   -(void)addItemViewController:(GeoCoding_controller *)controller didFinishEnteringItem:(NSString *)item{


double delay = 10.0;

dispatch_time_t poptime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delay * NSEC_PER_SEC);

dispatch_after(poptime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{


        NSArray *foo = [item componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

        NSString *address = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@",[foo objectAtIndex:0],[foo objectAtIndex:1],[foo objectAtIndex:2]];

        double lat = [[foo objectAtIndex:3]doubleValue];

        double lng =[[foo objectAtIndex:4] doubleValue];


        GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:lat longitude:lng zoom:18];

        MAP.camera = camera;

        edtaddress.text = address;



        NSLog(@"data from controller : %@", item);

    });
```

}

Comment: Please add the code to your question.

Comment: And please just post the relevant code. No need for the entire .h and .m files of both classes.

Comment: Sorry for not adding code at first!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't set the delegate for self, you should do:

```
self.delegate = first_cont;
```

after

```
First_view_controller *first_cont = [self .storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"first_view"];
```